# Error while creating JSON server in react

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm new to react and wanted to setup a JSON server for my project. I executed the below commands :

1. npm install -g json-server
2. json-server -watch src/users.json

But, it was not successful and I received the below log. Can you tell me how to proceed further for this.

```
 \{^_^}/ hi!

Loading –watch
Error: Unsupported source –watch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use regular hyphens for passing command line options:

```
json-server --watch src/users.json
```

Comment: Hello @robertklep thanks, now its working. But when I try opening http://localhost:3000/users on Browser, its not displaying the JSON data.

Comment: @VarshaSiva I can't help with that without knowing the contents of the JSON file you're serving.

Comment: {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Robert",
        "place_name": "abc",},
      {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Lucy",
        "place_name": "vfsg"
      },
    ]
  } - @robertklep

Comment: @VarshaSiva works fine for me.

Comment: Do I need to make any changes in package.json file? Because, I'm just getting a blank page - @robertklep